# The multiplication of complex number is giving wrong output in python

Tags: python, complex-numbers

My code is working fine for complex numbers addition, but the multiplication of complex numbers is giving the wrong output.

```
class Complex:
    def __init__(self, num):
        a = int(num[0])
        b = int(num[3])
        self.real = a
        self.complex = b

    def printcomplex(self):
        print(f"{self.real}+i{self.complex}")

    def add(self, other_complex):
        self.real = self.real + other_complex.real
        self.complex = self.complex + other_complex.complex

    def multiply(self, another):
        self.real = self.real * another.real - self.complex * another.complex
        self.complex = self.real * another.complex + self.complex * another.real

c = Complex("3+i3")
d = Complex("2+i2")
c.add(d)
c.printcomplex()
c.multiply(d)
c.printcomplex()
```

The code is taking two complex numbers `c` and `d` and multiplying `c` by `d` using the `multiply` method, giving the real and complex numbers of that multiplied result to `c`, and then printing it using the `printcomplex` method.
And the output is 5+i5- for addition and 0+i10- for multiplication.

Comment: You don't want "real" and "complex".  You want "real" and "imaginary".  Those are the correct names for the two components of a complex value.  Also, you do know that Python has builtin support for complex numbers, right?  In any case, the reason your multiplication is failing is because the second assignment (the one that assigns the imaginary part into the misnamed attribute "complex") is picking up the *new* value of `self.real`.  You need to use the old value.  Just save the new values into locals, then assign them both to `self.xxx` at the end.

Comment: ...and assuming that you are learning python and classes, have a look at `__add__` and `__mul__`, `__rmul__` etc. ..as well as `__str__` and `__repr__`

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that Python supports complex numbers natively?

```
[timr@Tims-Pro:~/src]$ python
Python 3.8.9 (default, Apr 13 2022, 08:48:07) 
[Clang 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> c = 3+3j
>>> d = 2+2j
>>> c+d
(5+5j)
>>> 
>>> c*d
12j
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with your implementation is the fact that it would break as soon as you enter a number such us 24+71i, since it's reliant on position of the imaginary part being at index 3 and that's only true if you have single digits in both numbers. Try using something like a tuple or list, or just use two arguments (like `__init__(self, real, imaginary)`) in your `__init__()` method.
If you really want to parse strings into your custom complex type look into regular expressions, as Python has quite a bit of support for them.
As the other commenter mentioned, your values are overwriting each other - the self.real in the second line is the new one you define in the line above, and you need to store the old values for use in calculation like this:

```
old_self_real = self.real
old_self_imaginary = self.imaginary
...
```

etc.
Also, look into using methods like `__add__()` for defining how to add objects. Then you can use the + operator.